# Where can I find the file for product view translation?

Tags: magento-1.9, localisation, translate

Does anyone know where to find the translation file for this line "`Buy 2 for $84.60...`" ?

I am trying to change the default **Chinese** text in the 2nd pic. I am using Magento ver. 1.9.2.4

Answer (score 0):

Translation file are located in the location bellow, you can change to this file to translate line or word.

`/var/www/html/a-pro/app/locale/en_US/Mage_Catalog.csv`

The best way to override Translation is to add a new `translate.csv` file in your theme in following path :

`app/design/frontend/default/default/locale/en_US/translate.csv`

Here is an [example](http://blog.chapagain.com.np/magento-override-default-language-translation/) to create new file in theme and translate word or lines.

Answer (score 0):

There are three options of translation in Magento :

1) Inline Translation = `System -> Configuration -> Developer -> Translate Inline`

2) Theme translation = `app/design/frontend/{yourpackage}/{yourtheme}/locale/language_ISO/translate.csv`

3) Module translations = `app/locale/{language_code}_{country_code}/{namespace}_{module}.csv`

So the easiest for you if you don't find the path, use the first method (1) it's the highest one of priority and the translation will be stored in the database.